# Unsure whether pip paths are correct

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, version

I use `pip` to install packages. Recently, I played around with pip and virtualenv and may have unintentionally messed up things in the process. When I check pip paths, I get the following:

```
pip -V # pip 20.2b1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-20.2b1-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)
pip3 -V # pip 20.2b1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-20.2b1-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)
```

However, I am unsure why both `pip` and `pip3` path to Python 2.7. Why is this the case? Does this mean that the pip I have is not compatible with Python 3.7 and if so how do I fix this?

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: Hint: [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). See `head -1 $(which pip)` and `head -1 $(which pip3)`. Edit `$(which pip3)` and fix the shebang.

Comment: Probably something went wrong at some point while installing Python and/or _pip_. You might want to reinstall those. To force a reinstallation of _pip_ itself, you might want to give `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed pip` a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have changed the Python `pip` installation path within your `virtualenv`

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file

There is a section here that explains how you can work around your installation path for `virtualenv`

> pip allows you to set all command line option defaults in a standard
> ini style config file.
>
> The names and locations of the configuration files vary slightly
> across platforms. You may have per-user, per-virtualenv or site-wide
> (shared amongst all users) configuration:
>
> Per-user:
>
> On Unix the default configuration file is: `$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf`
> which respects the `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` environment variable.
>
> On macOS the configuration file is `$HOME/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf`
> if directory `$HOME/Library/Application Support/pip` exists else
> `$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf`.
>
> **On Windows the configuration file is %`APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini`**.
>
> There are also a legacy per-user configuration file which is also
> respected, these are located at:
>
> On Unix and macOS the configuration file is: $HOME/.pip/pip.conf
>
> On Windows the configuration file is: %HOME%\pip\pip.ini
>
> You can set a custom path location for this config file using the
> environment variable PIP_CONFIG_FILE.
>
> **Inside a virtualenv:**
>
> **On Unix and macOS the file is `$VIRTUAL_ENV/pip.conf`**
>
> **On Windows the file is: `%VIRTUAL_ENV%\pip.ini`**
>
> Site-wide:
>
> On Unix the file may be located in `/etc/pip.conf`. Alternatively it may
> be in a “pip” subdirectory of any of the paths set in the environment
> variable `XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` (if it exists), for example
> `/etc/xdg/pip/pip.conf`.
>
> On macOS the file is: `/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf`
>
> On Windows XP the file is: `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\pip\pip.ini`
>
> On Windows 7 and later the file is hidden, but writeable at
> `C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini`
>
> Site-wide configuration is not supported on Windows Vista
>
> If multiple configuration files are found by pip then they are
> combined in the following order:
>
> The site-wide file is read
>
> The per-user file is read
>
> The virtualenv-specific file is read
>
> Each file read overrides any values read from previous files, so if
> the global timeout is specified in both the site-wide file and the
> per-user file then the latter value will be used.

You will have to edit a config file in pip directory and change the target to your Python 37 `site-packages` location

You may have to create the pip.ini file when you find your pip directory. Within your pip.ini or pip.config you will then need to put (assuming your on windows) something like

```
[global]
target = Target directory
```